# How to refresh a ListView, after changing the list to a new list?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `ListView` with default lists in the page. I want the list to be replaced with certain conditions to a new list of content in the list view. Somehow I am able to set the list.

The problem is that I need to replace /refresh the listview with new list of items.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the model object: `listView.setModelObject(List.of("new", "items"))`.

If you do this in an Ajax request then you will need to add the listView's parent component to the AjaxRequestTarget: `target.add(listView.getParent())`. You need to use the parent because repeater components render their markup for each item, so you need to re-render the markup that wraps the items.